# Powershell: Only export string values

Tags: powershell

I have a script that reads a text file, captures specific string values via select-string and then writes to a csv file. The issue I am having is it automatically adds additional columns I do not want:

*IgnoreCase LineNumber  Line    Filename    Path    Pattern Context Matches*

The string values I want are under **Line** - How do I have it output ONLY the string values I have captured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` to grab just a single property value from the [`MatchInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object that `Select-String` returns:

```
$MatchedStrings = Get-Item C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\en-US\about_Foreach.help.txt |select-string "operator"
$MatchedStrings | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line | Out-File C:\myStrings.txt
```

If you want to output to a single-column CSV file and retain the `Line` header, use `Select-Object -Property` instead:

```
$MatchedStrings | Select-Object -Property Line | Export-Csv C:\strings.csv -NoTypeInformation
```